# Simple puts() function in x64 assembly

Tags: strings, io, linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to write as simple I/O library in x64 using linux syscalls

```
section .text
strlen:
  xor rdx, rdx
  .loop:
  cmp [rsi + rdx], 0
  je .exit
  inc rdx
  jmp .loop
  .exit:
  ret ; value in rdx

puts:
  ; string passed through rsi
  mov rax, 1
  call strlen
  syscall
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5):

Your loop uses 2 jumps (`je`/`jmp`) on every iteration!  Jumping is expensive, so a solution that needs only 1 jump (`jne`) will be more effective.

```
strlen:
  xor rdx, rdx
  dec rdx          ; This compensates for the INC that is happening first.
.next:
  inc rdx
  cmp byte [rsi + rdx], 0
  jne .next
  ret
```

---

Do keep things logically together. There's no point in setting `RAX` before the call to *strlen*.

```
puts:
  ; string passed through rsi
  call strlen      ; Result is in RDX

  mov rax, 1
  syscall
```

Comment: Would it be best to make an generalization of this and cal it `fputs` then have puts just `mov rdi, 1` and call puts?

Answer (score 3):

The other review hit the most important parts, but there are a few more things to consider.

### Consider using the standard C interface

If the code is instead written like this:

```
; IN: rdi points to NUL-terminated string
; OUT: rax contains string length
strlen:
    xor rax, rax
    dec rax
.top:
    inc rax
    cmp byte [rdi + rax], 0
    jne .top
    ret
```

This would have the advantage of being callable from C.

### Use named constants

Instead of having "magic numbers" littering the code, it's better to define named constants.  For example the number `1` is used in two different ways; once for the `WRITE` syscall, and once for the `stdout` file handle.  I'd recommend defining and using one named constant for each.

### Consider more general usage

As you mention in a comment, the only difference between `puts` and `fputs` is the file handle.  In this case, one could get both `puts` and `fputs` very cheaply like this:

```
puts:
  mov rdi, 1 ; fd for stdout
fputs:
  call strlen
  mov rax, 1 ; WRITE syscall
  syscall
  ret
```

Note that this uses your existing calling convention rather than the C calling convention.

### Consider using macros

You may find it useful to define some macros for common things like this:

```
%macro SYSTEM 1
    mov rax, %1
    syscall
%endmacro

    WRITE: equ 1

    SYSTEM WRITE
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor point, but you can save code space and a little time (indirectly, by taking less space) by replacing loads like these

```
mov rax, 1 ; WRITE syscall
mov rdi, 1 ; fd for stdout
```

with 32bit `mov`:

```
mov eax, 1 ; WRITE syscall
mov edi, 1 ; fd for stdout
```

Writes to 32bit registers are zero-extended to the corresponding 64bit register so they are equivalent.

For example `mov rax, 1` might be encoded (depending on the assembler) as

```
48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00
```

While `mov eax, 1` may be encoded as

```
b8 01 00 00 00
```

The `b8+`-type mov in its 64bit form has an imm64 which would take even more bytes, the assembler can choose the `c7` form to avoid encoding a whole imm64 if the constant is small enough, but then unlike the `b8+`-form it needs a ModRM byte to encode the destination (the `c0` byte) and a REX.W prefix is still needed to encode to 64bitness of the instruction, at least if the assembler is faithful to the form as written.

Comment: what about mov al, 1

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy that only writes to the low byte of `rax`, so if there was some big value in it then it would stay big

Comment: It only goes to 316 so I could use ax

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy yes that saves an other byte, I wouldn't really recommend it in general since it would break whenever `rax` does turn out to have a larger value, it can also causs some odd partial register write performance impacts